# Image editing using python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an image. [image]

I want to erase its background and get a white or  transparent background preferably without the black dotes. I am trying PIL in python:

```
img1 = img.convert("L") 
img1.show() 
img1.save("im1.jpg")
```

and also

```
img2 = img.convert("1") 
img2.show() 
img1.save("im1.jpg")
```

This gives something like this:
[image]

Trying with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(img1,cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
plt.savefig("im1.jpg")
```

makes the background black, the original green as grey and the original black dots as white. [image]

Can you suggets what I can try?

Comment: usually you won't find much help on solving captchas. they are a fun challenge but if we tell you how to solve them, where is the fun? and if it is not just a fun challenge we would help you circumvent them where people put them in place to keep you out. that's not very ethical. also you should do your won research befor asking for help. I don't see this from your post

Comment: @Piglet Well I have tried CNN with emnist and captcha data but they did not help much with my captcha. Now I am trying to build my own dataset to make a CNN but it seems not the perfect answer.

Comment: your code only shows that you display the image. there is no effort to do any image processing. suggesting a solution for this image would not help you much as every image will be different. here you could simply extract green pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Piglet it is not fun if we tell you how to do it. To get you excited here is something I got when I played around:-

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('captcha.jpg')
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # Set minimum and maximum HSV values to display
hMin=0
sMin = 37
vMin = 0
hMax = 179
sMax = 255
vMax = 255

lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('image', result)
while 1==1:
    k=cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k==27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break;
```

Hope this gets you going...